# Error when trying to start an asynchronous task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In my start function I run 3 functions + print. I want my create_task to form 2 functions and execute them synchronously, which is what is happening now. At the same time I am trying to run asynchronous function say_hi() and I want it to be executed immediately at start time, without waiting for other functions to finish and without waiting for say_hi function itself to be executed. How can I run it? If I remove await, I get an error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'say_hi' was never awaited say_hi()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

code:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

async def say_hi():
  task = asyncio.sleep(1)
  print("HI")
  await task


async def start():
  asyncio.create_task(write_file())
  await say_hi()
  asyncio.create_task(take_time(time=datetime.now()))
  print("hi")


async def main():
  tasks = [
    start(),
  ]
  await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use another `asyncio.gather` to execute `write_file()`, `take_time()` and `say_hi()` tasks concurrently:

```py
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime


async def write_file():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("write file")


async def take_time(time):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("take time")


async def say_hi():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("HI")


async def start():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(write_file())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(say_hi())
    t3 = asyncio.create_task(take_time(time=datetime.now()))
    await asyncio.gather(t1, t2, t3)
    print("hi")


async def main():
    tasks = [
        start(),
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
HI
write file
take time
hi
```